# enhanced for loop not working

Tags: c++, sfml

The main question is, why does the regular for loop work and the enhanced for loop doesn't. The description of the not working enhanced for loop is down below.

SOLVED!!! I will leave my description to the problem down below, but I did some playing around with the code and found out you can't move sprites via enhanced for loops. You need an actual for loop. Look at my updateSprites function the (what I just implemented) workingUpdateSprites function.

(previous problem I had before you PROBABLY can ignore it)
SFML isn't moving my sprite to the right at all. I have an updateSprites function that moves idle frames to the right (for experimental reasons) which gets called by the player update function then by the Engine update function. The sprites are displayed by returning a sprite to the main Engine and simply drawing it.

```
Player.cpp
<i>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Engine.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#define _MYDEBUG1



void Player::updateSprites() {                         //Changes x and y variables for EVERY player sprite upon each iteration of the game loop
     for (Sprite i : idle)
          i.move(1, 0);
}
//idk why the for loop works and the enhanced one doesn't.
void Player::workingUpdateSprites() {                         //Changes x and y variables for EVERY player sprite upon each iteration of the game loop
     for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(idle); i++)
          idle[i].move(1, 0);
}

void Player::update() {                                     //God method that updates the player class {accessed by main engine}
     updateVisuals();
}

void Player::updateVisuals() {
     updateSprites();
}

Sprite Player::getPlayerSprite() {                                                            //return image of player sprite to get printed in the engine file
     if (movement->getDirection() == 0) {                                                     //also determines which sprite to send and at what frame
          int amtFrameTimePerSprite = frameIdleMaxCounterVal / ARRAYSIZE(idle);               //gets amount of frame time per sprite
          if (frameIdleMaxCounterVal - frameIdleCounter > amtFrameTimePerSprite)               //divides frameIdleCount by amtFrameTimePerSprite to get exact index
               return idle[(int)floor(frameIdleCounter / amtFrameTimePerSprite)];
          else
               return idle[ARRAYSIZE(idle) - 1];
     }
     return idle[0];
}

Player::Player(int x, int y) {             //Constructs superclass(es) and sprites
     frameIdleMaxCounterVal = 240;

///////-----------------------------------------------------CONSTRUCION OF ALL PLAYER SPRITES BEGINS----------------------------------------////////////////
     //constructs idle sprites into array
     for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(tIdle); i++) {
          if (i == 3) {
               if (!tIdle[i].loadFromFile("resources\\player\\playerSass\\playerSass1.png")) {
                    throw "Could not load player idle frames";
               }
          }
          else {
               if (!tIdle[i].loadFromFile("resources\\player\\playerSass\\playerSass" + std::to_string(i) + ".png"))
                    throw "could not load player idle frames";
          }
          idle[i].setTexture(tIdle[i]);
          idle[i].setPosition(x, y);
     }
     //constructs movement up sprites into array
     for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(tMvtUp); i++) {
          if (!tMvtUp[i].loadFromFile("resources\\player\\playerSass\\mvtUp\\playerMvtUp" + std::to_string(++i) + ".png"))
               throw "could not load player movement up frames";
          mvtUp[i].setTexture(tMvtUp[i]);
          mvtUp[i].setPosition(x, y);
     }
     //constructs movement down sprites into array
     for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(tMvtDown); i++) {
          if (!tMvtDown[i].loadFromFile("resources\\player\\playerSass\\mvtDown\\playerMvtDown" + std::to_string(++i) + ".png"))
               throw "could not load player movement down frames";
          mvtDown[i].setTexture(tMvtDown[i]);
          mvtDown[i].setPosition(x, y);
     }
     //constructs movement left sprites into array
     for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(tMvtLeft); i++) {
          if (!tMvtLeft[i].loadFromFile("resources\\player\\playerSass\\mvtLeft\\playerMvtLeft" + std::to_string(++i) + ".png"))
               throw "could not load player movement left frames";
          mvtLeft[i].setTexture(tMvtLeft[i]);
          mvtLeft[i].setPosition(x, y);
     }
     //constructs movement down sprites into array
     for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(tMvtRight); i++) {
          if (!tMvtRight[i].loadFromFile("resources\\player\\playerSass\\mvtRight\\playerMvtRight" + std::to_string(++i) + ".png"))
               throw "could not load player movement right frames";
          mvtRight[i].setTexture(tMvtRight[i]);
          mvtRight[i].setPosition(x, y);
     }
     ///////------------------------------------CONSTRUCTION OF ALL PLAYER ANIMATION FRAMES END---------------------------------------------------//////////

     //////-------------------------------------CONSTRUCIION OF MOVEMENT-----------------------------------------------
     movement = new Movement(x, y);
}
</i>
```

Player.h

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Movement.h"
#ifndef _PLAYER_H
#define _PLAYER_H

using namespace sf;

class Player {
private:
     Movement *movement;
     Sprite idle[4], mvtUp[8], mvtDown[8], mvtLeft[8], mvtRight[8];
     Texture tIdle[4], tMvtUp[8], tMvtDown[8], tMvtLeft[8], tMvtRight[8];
     int frameIdleCounter = 1, frameIdleMaxCounterVal = 20;

     void updateVisuals();
     void updateCounters();
     void updateSprites();
public:
     Sprite getPlayerSprite();
     int getX();
     int getY();

     void update();

     Player(int x, int y);
};
#endif
```

Engine.cpp

```
#include "Engine.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#define _PAUSEDISPLAYl
#define _MYDEBUGf

bool Engine::init() {
#ifdef _MYDEBUG
     freopen("conin$", "r", stdin);
     freopen("conout$", "w", stdout);
     freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);
#endif
     window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "RPG", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Resize);
     window->setFramerateLimit(60);
     player = new Player(50, 50);
     if (!window)
          return false;
     return true;
}

void Engine::mainLoop() {
     //Loop until window is closed
     while (window->isOpen()) {
          processInput();
          update();
          window->clear(sf::Color::Black);
          renderFrame();
          window->display();
#ifdef _PAUSEDISPLAY
          system("pause");
#endif
     }
}

void Engine::processInput() {
     sf::Event evt;
     //loops through all window events
     while (window->pollEvent(evt)) {

          //window events
          switch (evt.type) {
          case sf::Event::Closed:
               window->close();
          case sf::Event::Resized:
               std::cout << "width " << evt.size.width << " height " << evt.size.height;
               break;
          }
     }
}

void Engine::update() {             //the actual god method 
     player->update();
}

void Engine::renderFrame() {             //calls object sprites to then be printed/displayed on the screen
     window->draw(player->getPlayerSprite());
}

void Engine::go() {
     if (!init())
          throw "Initialization of Engine has Failed";
     mainLoop();
}
Engine::Engine() {
}


Engine::~Engine() {
}
```

Engine.h

```
#ifndef _ENGINE_H
#define _ENGINE_H

#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Input.h"

class Engine {
private:
     sf::RenderWindow* window;
     Player *player;

     bool init();

     void mainLoop();

     void processInput();

     void update();

     void renderFrame();

public:
     Engine();
     ~Engine();

     void go();

     Input input[4];
};

#endif
```

Comment: Even though your problem is solved, you should consider editing your question. I say this, because the question title is actually quite useful in my opinion (don't hate me guys, *XY not working* is the first thing to push into google) but the question itself is not very helpful. If you reduce it to the actual problem: non-working enhanced loop vs. working normal loop, without all the surrounding code, it can form a good starting point for others with a similar problem. Sidenote: I didn't -1 this, but as it stands the -1 is probably deserved.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely **can** use range-based for loops with sprites, you were just using them incorrectly, by modifying a temporary copy inside your loop instead of the original sprite. Try using a reference instead:

```
for (Sprite& i : idle)
      i.move(1, 0);
```